# Are there any common uses of C# do-while loop in web development?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, razor

I've been coding for a long, long time, self-taught. Now that I'm working toward my computer science degree, my programming class is talking about post-test loops, the do-while loop.

Now I understand that it runs once, then checks the condition...  since I'm a web programmer, I was wondering: what are some common web development (ASP.NET MVC/Razor preferably) scenarios where a do-while loop fits perfectly?

I'm not quite getting the concept straight in my mind...

Comment: This question is like asking in what scenarios is a screwdriver a good fit.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that's true. So let's say the do-while loop is a flat-head screwdriver. What's the fit?

Comment: I hope Eric Lippert happens to notice this question, I'd be curious to see his take on do/while and why he chose to include it. My guess is that there was just no reason to get rid of it.

Comment: @Justin: Remember, I joined the C# team during the development of C# 3.0. I was working on JScript during the development of C# 1.0. I didn't make the decisions about what loops went into C# 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

I have been involved in many web projects and I can't remember for any specific use for this type of a loop. On web, you usually work just with collection of items and do some logic with each one of them. So I would say that most web developers just use `foreach` and `for`.

Do - While fits more into algorithms and calculations, and you don't do many of these in classic web development imo.

Comment: I see... perhaps that is why I haven't seen one in use for web development (many times, the deep business logic code may run some algorithms, but that wouldn't be shared very often). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about MVC specifically, but a couple of years ago I had to create a administration page to enter data, on the client side you could add new fields to add staff member profiles. (name, title, education)

The controls were created client-side with JavaScript and numbered in sequence like:

*txtStaffName0*

*txtStaffName1*

*txtStaffName2*

Then used a do/while with the condition checking for the next incremented number for a control. Something along the lines of:

```
int count = 0;
do
{
   //find control with count and do stuff...
   count++;
} while (DoesControlExist(count));
```

Apart from that I don't think I've ever seen do/while used in web related stuff...

Comment: exactly, I've never run into it... I asked because maybe I'm missing out on a worthy technique. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As most of the interface logic has been implemented at client side (to save bandwidth and for performance reasons), so this loop has almost no need . Also the difference between program flow in a web and console (or windows application) is that web page run in a context for many users while windows application is used mostly by a single user where user can have option to manage control flow like continue or exit.

Comment: Thanks... what sort of things - not client side - would a do-while loop be used for?

Answer (score 0):

I bet the syntax reveal it all, if having a situation the you need to perform first before checking.

```
        do {
            // Do your algo first.
        } while (true); // Check later.
```

Now in real code, I can assume:

```
        int x = 100;
        do {
            x = y - 10;
        } while (x >= 0);
```

Its like to concept of `x++` and `++x` inside the for loop of C, it makes you decide to increment now or later.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience usage of loops varies as per requirment.

If you iterate through a collection and do some action for each object in a collection, for each would be safe from run-time exception.

But for each doesn't work if you want to remove an item from collection based on a condition, there for loop is the best one. do from collection.count() - 1 to 0.

Usual for loop is used to execute some action or calculation.

Personally i rarely use do while.

Answer (score 0):

I very nearly asked this exact question yesterday. In all my years of web development, I can't think of a single time I've used a do/while in production code. On the other hand, I hardly ever use recursion either, but on those few occasions when I want it, it's good to have.

Anyway, [this article](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson04.aspx) suggests using it in a console app to show a menu and redraw it after every input. Here's an edited snippet of the article's code:

```
   string myChoice;

   do
   {
        // Print A Menu
        Console.WriteLine("My Address Book\n");
        Console.WriteLine("A - Add New Address");
        Console.WriteLine("D - Delete Address");
        Console.WriteLine("Q - Quit\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Choice (A,D,M,V,or Q): ");

        // Retrieve the user's choice
        myChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        // Make a decision based on the user's choice
        switch(myChoice)
        {
            case "A":
                Console.WriteLine("You wish to add an address.");
                break;
            case "D":
                Console.WriteLine("You wish to delete an address.");
                break;
            case "Q":
                Console.WriteLine("Bye.");
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    } while (myChoice != "Q"); // Keep going until the user wants to quit
```

This seems reasonably useful. You could, of course, get around it by setting the initial value of `myChoice` to something other than "Q", or by adding a bool to the `while` condition, or something like that, but do/while gets the job done marginally easier. It's not essential like recursion is; I don't think there's much (if anything) that do/while does *significantly* better than while. But it's a holdover from C and it's occasionally useful, so there's no reason to get rid of it.